Unexpected output in Python REPL using VS Code on Windows
I have VS Code set up with Python extension, but without Jupyter extension.
VS Code lets you send Python code from the editor to what it calls the "Native REPL" (a Jupyter-type interface without full notebook capabilities) or the "Terminal REPL" (the good old Python >>> prompt). See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/run.
I prefer working in the Terminal REPL. I have my keyboard shortcuts configured to use Ctrl+Enter (instead of Shift+Enter) to send the selection to the terminal:
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "python.execSelectionInTerminal",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !isCompositeNotebook && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "command": "-python.execSelectionInTerminal",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !isCompositeNotebook && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
    }
]

On Linux, this works as expected.
Editor:
print("Hello, World!")

What happens in terminal:
>>> print("Hello, world!")
Hello, world!

On Windows, the same actions (select line, hit Ctrl+Enter) produces the following:
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> print("Hello, world!")
Hello, world!

This might be some harmless little visual noise, but it seems to be interfering with plotting. When I initialize a plot with:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

print("Hello, world!") now generates the following:
>>> print("Hello, world!")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 0, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt

Note that putting code directly into the terminal (instead of using VS Code's send-to-terminal feature) still functions normally.
How can I fix the send-to-terminal feature?

Roll back your python extension to 14.0 and disable auto-update will fix the issue.
Reference:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/24251

This worked perfectly. Thanks for the find.
